# AppleScript error with if statement

Tags: applescript

I have a long script that I use for a while but just realise that I have an error.

The first parameter of the if statement don't seems to be taken in consideration

```
set GUID to "demo"
set FoundGUID to "Not good"
set trustitemOnMyList to "TRUST"
set trustitemOnMyList to "2step"

if GUID is equal to FoundGUID and trustitemOnMyList is equal to "TRUST" or trustitemOnMyList is equal to "2step" then
    display notification "True"
end if
```

In this case GUID and FoundGUID is not equal but the script seems to ignore this.

PS: to make it more clear, to be valid, I need the GUID to be the same than FoundGUID, and I need trustitemOnMyList to be either equal to "TRUST" or to "2step"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless indicated otherwise, the comparisons are performed in order from left to right, so you just need to group them, e.g. `x and (y or z)` instead of `x and y or z`, otherwise that last `or` can decide:

```
if GUID is equal to FoundGUID and (trustitemOnMyList is equal to "TRUST" or trustitemOnMyList is equal to "2step")
    -- or --
if GUID = FoundGUID and trustitemOnMyList is in {"TRUST", "2step"}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's easier, I'll try this now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping for another another but otherwise I guess I can do the following :

```
set GUID to "demo"
set FoundGUID to "deddmo"
set trustitemOnMyList to "TRUST"
set trustitemOnMyList to "2step"
set guidfound to false
set trusteddevice to false

if GUID is equal to FoundGUID then
    set guidfound to true
end if

if trustitemOnMyList is equal to "TRUST" then
    set trusteddevice to true
end if

if trustitemOnMyList is equal to "2step" then
    set trusteddevice to true
end if

if guidfound is true and trusteddevice is true then
    display notification "true"
end if
```

I setup multiple if-statements which set variable as Boolean, then I add a final if-statement with this only two statement.